# Unable to initialise Solr in Github workflow

Tags: git, go, github, solr, workflowservice

This is the GitHub action file that I  have used in the workflows.

.github/workflows/go.yml

```
name: Go

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master development ]
    tags:
      - '*'
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - '*'
jobs:
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: [self-hosted, linux]
    services:
      solr:
        image: solr
        ports:
          - 2010:8983
        options: solr:8.3.1 - cloud
    steps:
    - name: Set up Go 1.x
      uses: actions/setup-go@v2
      with:
        go-version: ^1.14
      id: go

    - name: Check out code into the Go module directory
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
     
    - name: Get dependencies
      run: |
        go get -v -t -d ./...
       
    - name: Test
      run: |
        mkdir build
           go test ./... -v -coverprofile build/coverage.txt -coverpkg=./...
        cat build/coverage.txt | grep -v '.pb.go' > build/coverage.out
        go tool cover -func build/coverage.out
       
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: build artifacts
        path: build
```

In the result of  the workflow  I am getting `connection refused`,  Workflow is able to pull the Solr container but, in my test, I am getting the following  error:

Get "http://localhost:2010/solr/customer/select?q=id%3A2+\u0026wt=json": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2010: connect: connection refused"

Since the  Solr container has been pulled, I am expecting my test to successfully hit the Solr API.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your "options" setting is actually passing args to the container that make the service error out. At least, when I try them locally that's what seems to be happening. Try your service setup this way to get the explicit version you want:

```
  services:
    solr:
      image: solr:8.3.1
      ports:
        - 2010:8983
```

It can be a bit difficult to debug service container startup. But if you dig around in the action logs you should find some clues.

Comment: @mikerowehi, Getting the same error as before. Below is the log, I got for the container startup 
```/usr/bin/docker pull solr:8.3.1

  8.3.1: Pulling from library/solr
…
   /usr/bin/docker create --name solr831_d30703 --label 7784cf --network github_network …  --network-alias solr -p 2010:8983  -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true solr:8.3.1
  /usr/bin/docker start <container id>
  /usr/bin/docker ps --all --filter id=<container id>  --filter status=running --no-trunc --format "{{.ID}} {{.Status}}"
 <container id> Up Less than a second
 /usr/bin/docker port <container id>```

Comment: It looks like the solr container takes a long time to start up. I just tried creating a test at github and it was a few seconds before the container was actually serving requests. So just add a healthcheck to make sure solr is serving requests, and the github workflow will make sure the container is healthy before starting your steps. Like this: https://github.com/mikerowehl/solrtest/blob/main/.github/workflows/solr.yml

Comment: Solr is getting connected. But the error I  am getting is `"msg":"Solr instance is not running in SolrCloud mode." ` @mikerowehi

Comment: I can't really help with the Solr setup part, I'm not very familiar with how to use it. Please accept the answer for getting the go app in your workflow connecting to the Solr instance.